# Failed to run the pipeline (Pipeline) - Azure Data Factory

Tags: debugging, azure-data-factory

For testing purposes I'm trying to execute this simple pipeline (nothing sophisticated).

[image]

However, I'm getting this error:

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":null,"target":"pipeline//runid/cb841f14-6fdd-43aa-a9c1-4619dab28cdd","details":null,"error":null}
```

The goal is to see if two variables are getting the right values (we have been facing some issues in our production environment).

This is the json with the definition of the pipeline:

```
{
"name": "GeneralTest",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Set variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "start_time",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@utcnow()",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Wait1",
            "type": "Wait",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "waitTimeInSeconds": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable2",
            "description": "",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Wait1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "end_time ",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@utcnow()",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "start_time": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "end_time ": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "folder": {
        "name": "Old Pipelines"
    },
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

What am I missing, or what could be the problem with this process?

Comment: How are you executing the pipeline?

Comment: Using the Debug Option

Comment: Does it validate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a **"blank space"** after the variable name `end_time` like **"end_time "**

[image]

You can see the difference in my repro:
MyCode VS YourCode

[image]

Clearing that would make the execution just fine.

[image]

Comment: crazy, did validation work? I have the same meaningless error, validation passed but pipeline cannot run :(

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue when doing a Debug run of one of my pipelines. The error messages for these types of errors are not helpful when running in Debug mode.

What I have found is that if you publish the pipeline and then Trigger a Pipeline Run (instead of a Debug run), you can then go to Monitor Pipeline Runs and it will show you a more useful error message.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from possible blank spaces in variable or parameter names, Data Factory doesn't like hyphens, but only in parameter names, variables are fine.

Validation passes, but then in debug time you get the same cryptic error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error message in Data Factory today on the Copy activity. Everything passed validation but this error would pop on each debug run.

I have parameters configured on my dataset connections so that I can use dynamic queries against the data sources. In this case, I was using explicit queries, so the parameters appeared irrelevant. I tried with both blank values and value is null. Both failed the same way.

I tried with stupid but real text values and it worked! The pipeline isn't leveraging the stupid values for any work, so their content doesn't matter, but some portion of the engine needs a non-null value in the parameters in order to execute.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible situation for it is spaces inside **Data Flow** names. No matter if they are in the end or in the middle of the name. You will be able to debug **Data Flow** but not the **Pipeline**

Answer (score 0):

i had also faced same issue in my ADF. i found the issue and have removed un-used variables and un used values in user properties of copy activity. it solved my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, its all leads to empty value/space in parameters. In my case I missed to set the parameter value for REST API dataset's parameter.